# Align checkbox with checkbox group horizontally in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

My application (based on Vaadin 8) has a `CheckBox` and a `CheckBoxGroup` wrapped in a `HorizontalLayout`.

```java
CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox("My Checkbox");

CheckBoxGroup<String> multi = new CheckBoxGroup<>("Multiple Selection");
multi.setItems("Many", "Muchos", "Monta");
multi.setCaption(null);
multi.addStyleName(ValoTheme.OPTIONGROUP_HORIZONTAL);

checkBoxLayout.addComponents(myCheckBox, multi);
checkBoxLayout.setComponentAlignment(myCheckBox, BOTTOM_LEFT);
checkBoxLayout.setComponentAlignment(multi, BOTTOM_LEFT);

this.addComponent(checkBoxLayout);
```

The problem is that the horizontal alignment of the checkbox and the checkbox group is not correct.

[image: screenshot without caption]

Setting the checkbox group caption to `null` does not help either. I suppose that the checkbox group has some additional spacing which could cause this behavior. How can I make sure that the horizonal alignment is working as used with `setComponentAlignment`?

[image: screenshot with caption]

#### Update 1

The solution suggested by @ollitietavainen (using `MIDDLE_CENTER`) results in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing else than the checkboxes inside the HorizontalLayout, using `Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER` seems to work better than `BOTTOM_LEFT`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue. It looks as if this is more of a general problem. See my original question update for a screenshot.

Comment: In that case, you're probably left with needing to align the items exactly with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the CheckBoxGroupState.primaryStyleName "v-select-optiongroup" style name than along with the alignment suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/65180983/12854146 I have the following code
[image]

```
    HorizontalLayout checkBoxLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    checkBoxLayout.setMargin(true);
    CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox("My Checkbox");

    CheckBoxGroup<String> multi = new CheckBoxGroup<>("Multiple Selection");
    multi.setItems("Many", "Muchos", "Monta");
    multi.setCaption(null);
    multi.addStyleName(ValoTheme.OPTIONGROUP_HORIZONTAL);
    multi.removeStyleNames("v-select-optiongroup");

    checkBoxLayout.addComponents(myCheckBox, multi);
    checkBoxLayout.setComponentAlignment(myCheckBox, MIDDLE_CENTER);
    checkBoxLayout.setComponentAlignment(multi, MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

you may have a similar output if you do not remove the style name "v-select-optiongroup" from multi and instead you add it to your checkbox with

```
myCheckBox.addStyleName("select-optiongroup");
```